# How to use Share Intent from gridview in soft keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard, ime, soft-keyboard

I have a gridview in a keyboardview that consist of images. i want to make every image in that gridview can be shared via intent share. how can i do that?

Thanks in advance

This is the code in the keyboard.class:

```
    public View buatQuoteView(){
    buatInputView(R.layout.quoteview, R.id.emptyKbd, R.xml.empty);

    final GridView gridView = (GridView) root.findViewById(R.id.quote_grid);
    gridView.setAdapter(new QuoteGrid(this));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // what should i put here????????
        }
    });
    return root;
}
```

this is the code in the QuoteGrid.class:

```
public class QuoteGrid extends BaseAdapter {
public Context mContext;

public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.quote1, R.drawable.quote2, R.drawable.quote3, R.drawable.quote4, R.drawable.quote5};

// Constructor
public QuoteGrid(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(250, 250));
    return imageView;
}
```

}

Comment: Click the grid view item and share intent features. It's correct???

Comment: In gridview your loading drawable image or server image url?

Comment: @MakeitSimple i'm serving drawable images

Answer (score 0):

Girdview have setOnItemClickListener(view,..postion) method

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

you can get position of the image then you can share image